# Can the coefficients and standard errors for a nested model be derived from the variance-covariance matrix of the full model

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, covariance-matrix

If you have a generalised linear model like this:-
$$
f(y) =  \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2
$$
and you know the coefficients and variance covariance matrix for the betas, but don't have access to the original data, can you estimate the coefficients for the following model:-
$$
f(y) =  \alpha_0 + \alpha_1x_1 
$$
$y$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the same for both models.

Comment: How does your "generalised linear model" differ from ordinary least squares regression?

Comment: @whuber. Thanks. This is my understanding of GLMs. Where the link function, f, is the identify function, and we assume that the variance of y is normally distributed, a GLM is just ordinary least squared regression. A GLM can, however, take different link functions and distributions (eg Poisson distribution and log-link for Poisson regression is a class of GLM). In other applications with GLMs I have seen the assumption that the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients has a mulitivariate-normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation: at the outset it isn't clear that $f$ is the link function because you have neglected to indicate the other part of the model; namely, the response distribution.  This made your formulation ambiguous.  However, you do know that OLS is a special case of a GLM and the answer to your question is obviously in the negative in that situation.  (If it's not entirely obvious, reduce the complexity by dropping the variable $x_1.$  You cannot estimate the mean of the responses based on simple regression coefficients unless the regressor has zero mean.)

Comment: Thanks @whuber. Sorry for the incomplete description. If I additionally knew (or was willing to assume) the joint distribution of X, but didn't have y, could I estimate the smaller set of coefficients (alpha)? I can see how I could do this by simulation, but wondered if I could do so analytically.

Comment: You could do this, but only in special cases.  The most important such case is where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent. Another case is where you have the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ depends on $x_1.$ Apart from such cases, it will be difficult, because in general you need more information: you are missing the covariance between $x_2$ and $y.$

Comment: Great thanks. That's really helpful.